# How do I create a program that presses a key in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, macros, keyboard

I am trying to create a macro program in C++.
The program is supposed to press the H key once in every 10 seconds.
I have got the timing functions already, but how do I make it hit a key?
So while the program runs, if I go to Notepad and leave it there, it would type "hhhhhhhh(...)"

Thanks!

Comment: @chris you should add that as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate a key press in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607849/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

A quick search turns up this question has been answered before:
[How to simulate a key press in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607849/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c)

Their accepted answer was to use [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It completely depends on your idea in mind, but i personnaly find that if i want to make some kind of macro program [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is THE way to go.