# Simulating a hardware key press in Java without Robot

Tags: java

I currently have a PS1 controller going through my Arduino sending messages to a Java program which then reads them and presses the correct key using a Robot. The problem with this is that the Robot class cannot send key presses to most applications and therefore will not send key presses to games which I would like to control using the PS1 controller. How are keyboard presses simulated without the use of a Robot, on a hardware level? I have previously tried having it run a Visual Basic Script, and it worked, but was much too slow. Is there any way to do it purely in java?

Comment: You could use JNA or JNI to do it.

Comment: @BevynQ How might that be done? After some Google searching, I came up with nothing but 'use Robot'

Comment: I assume your vbscript is making some windows calls? You can do that with JNA. It might be easier to do this in C# though.

Comment: @BevynQ Well, it doesn't seem as if that will work. The vbscript won't send key presses to a fullscreen window.

Comment: See this question for some advice doing it in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607849/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c. JNA or JNI can probably call the C++ code, but I know nothing about actually doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Java Native Access (JNA) enables to access the Native levels of Operating systems using Pure Java. You can access the JNA Project [here](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Furthermore I found a sample which uses JNA to Hook on to Hardware Keyboard to listen to key presses. I think [this](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java) is what you looking for.

If it is not what you are looking for, then you can definitely look through the reference and implement your own.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I've decided to go with having Java call a native function from a C++ program. After hunting around for a while I couldn't find out if JNA could even perform the necessary function.