# How to make a c++ program physically press a key?

Tags: c++, key

Now, i've been trying to make a C++ program that physically presses the <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> key, I am still a beginner in C++ and most recent thing i've learned is while loops. Thanks for anyone that could help :)

I want to do this because in a game I play, you go idle then you get kicked out for being idle. Thats why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: You want to simulate a keypress? Because *physically* pressing a key requires something... well, *physical*.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a way to do this, you'll have to look at the API for your platform.

Comment: Huh? Build a robot that physically presses the key?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like OP wants to send a signal to the game that a key was pressed repeatedly to prevent idle kicks. Sounds tricky.

Comment: Is this on microsoft windows? If so one way is to send window messages to the window that you want to receive the keypress.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I am on windows 7 and on visual studio 2012

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, I think this is achievable using the `SendInput` function to inject key presses into the target application.

You can find the API documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

See [how to use sendinput function C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419038/how-to-use-sendinput-function-c/22419083#22419083) for an explanation and a complete example of its use.