# How to have C++ press keys at random

Tags: c++, random

I am looking at creating a program that rolls 5 random numbers, and depending on what those numbers are it press 5 different keys.

I know how to generate 5 different random numbers, but how can I have it simulate key presses so it works in a different application? I'm going to use it to randomly buy stuff in a game. I read that it's Keypress() but I'm not sure what the syntax is. I don't need anything other than the context to use the command in

Thanks!

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607849/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linux, you can Use X11 like this

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>

Display *display;
unsigned int keycode;
display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
...
keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Pause);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);
XFlush(display);
```

In compilation link you must use -lX11 -lXtst.
In windows, you can use [send_input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)