# Intercept keyboard key presses

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to hear the beep without seeing 'B' as output on Notepad. How can I implement this?

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('B') & 0x8000)
{
    Beep( 500, 500 );
}
```

Comment: You could trigger a backspace, sort of a hack not sure if that would work.
If that works for you, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607849/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-in-c

Comment: I don't think SendInput and  keybd_event would my solve question. My goal is to detect key press and not see output on any text document app while hearing a beep

Comment: @dav: How would this pan out in case the `'B'` is pressed as part of a keyboard shortcut? No, I'm afraid, this is not a solution or even part of a solution. Installing a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Use a keyboard hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw). When your hook callback detects the desired key stroke, you can block the key stroke so it is not passed on to subsequent hooks or the target application.